# STLINK cannot detect my STM32VL discovery

Tags: usb, debian, stm32ldiscovery

I'm working on a debian 6.0 installed on virtualbox 4 hosted by Windows7, and I'm trying to get my STM32VL work using STLINK project that allows programming and debugging STM32 on Linux. 
I followed their tutorial and installed all needed dependancies.
But when I run the program `./​​st-util -1`, I get the following error:

```
tbarry@darkstar:~/stlink$ ./st-util -1
2014-03-20T10:18:48 WARN src/stlink-sg.c: Failed to find an stlink v1 by VID:PID
Error: could not open stlink device
Error: could not open stlink device
```

I underline that I have already installed Virtualbox extensions, and usb 2.0 is well handled.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​what is blocking me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not having found a solution to my problem, I tried with VMware player and it worked nice.
 
Conclusion: Whatever the problem I had, it was coming from VirtualBox.

Comment: I rather belong to VirtualBox sect :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd same problem. It was driver problem. Windows detected my st-link as mass storage device, so st-util didn't see it. I've used zadig utility in order to change the driver.